# Cloud Dataflow Resource Share Pool

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I wanted to check if there is scenario where there are 30-40 jobs running concurrently in cloud dataflow. Is there a setting by which the workers used on 1 job can be shared across other or use managed instance group as compute option.

The reason for asking is if the risk of running out of compute instances or exceeding the quota can be managed.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Dataflow manages the GCE instances internally. This means that it is unable to share the instances with other jobs. Please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#workers) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response, would you be knowing if cloud dataflow has any roadmap to have shared resource pooling.